# power bi - custom visual - matrix selection not update other visual

Tags: matrix, powerbi, selection, powerbi-custom-visuals

this same question with [power bi - forum - developer](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/matrix-selection-error-on-other-visual/m-p/779775#M20564)

i try create selection with my matrix custom visual, but that make error on other visual

this is my transform, using builder withMatrixNode

```
function visualTransform(options: VisualUpdateOptions, host: IVisualHost): DataViewModel {

let dataViews = options.dataViews[0];
var rows = dataViews.matrix.rows;
let listSelectionId: DataListSelection[] = [];
let selectionIdBuilder = host.createSelectionIdBuilder();

rows.root.children.forEach(x => {
    listSelectionId.push({
        value: x.value,
        selectionId: selectionIdBuilder.withMatrixNode(x, rows.levels).createSelectionId()
    });

    if (x.children)
        x.children.forEach(z => {
            listSelectionId.push({
                value: z.value,
                selectionId: selectionIdBuilder.withMatrixNode(z, rows.levels).createSelectionId()
            });
            if (z.children)
                z.children.forEach(a => {
                    listSelectionId.push({
                        value: a.value,
                        selectionId: selectionIdBuilder.withMatrixNode(a, rows.levels).createSelectionId()
                    });

                })
        })
});
return {
    dataPoints: listSelectionId
}
```

}

I'm already add click listener to get selection Id and make it selected in manager, and this is the console log
[image]

but but my page always got error in other visual:
[image]

what wrong with my selection code?
and one more question, I'm already declare selectcallback in my manager but never called when other visual make selection

```
this.selectionManager = this.host.createSelectionManager();
    console.log('constructor allow interaction', this.host.allowInteractions);
    this.selectionManager.registerOnSelectCallback(() => {
        console.log('selection manager callback', this.selectionManager.getSelectionIds());
    });
    this.selectionIdBuilder = options.host.createSelectionIdBuilder();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve this with remove let

```
let selectionIdBuilder = host.createSelectionIdBuilder();
```